# Can you change a file content during git commit?

Tags: git, hook, commit

One of the things I keep in my [open novel in GitHub](http://jj.github.io/hoborg/) is a [list of words](https://github.com/JJ/hoborg/blob/master/text/words.dic) I would like to set automatically the first line, which is the number of words in the dictionary. My first option is to write a pre-commit hook that reads the file, counts the words, rewrites the first line and writes it back again. Here's the code

```
PRE_COMMIT {
  my ($git) = @_;
  my $branch =  $git->command(qw/rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD/);
  say "Pre-commit hook in $branch";
  if ( $branch =~ /master/ ) {
     my $changed = $git->command(qw/show --name-status/);
     my @changed_files = ($changed =~ /\s\w\s+(\S+)/g);
     if ( $words ~~ @changed_files ) {
       my @words_content = read_file( $words );
       say "I have $#words_content words";
       $words_content[0] = "$#words_content\n";
       write_file( $words, @words_content );
     }
   }
};
```

However, since the file has already been staged, I get this error

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by checkout: 
>     text/words.dic 
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them
>   before you can switch branches. 
>   Aborting

Might it be better to do it as a post-commit hook and have it changed for the next commit? Or do something completely different altogether? The general question is: if you want to process and change the contents of a file during commit, what's the proper way of doing it?

Comment: For commit date, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699631/can-git-committer-date-be-customized-inside-a-git-hook

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The actual commit stuck in by `git commit` is whatever is in the index once the pre-commit hook finishes.  This means that you *can* change files in the pre-commit hook, as long as you `git add` them too.

Here's my example pre-commit hook, modified from the .sample:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
# [snipped much of what used to be in it, added this --
#  make sure you take out the exec of git diff-index!]

num=$(cat zorg)
num=$(expr 0$num + 1)
echo $num > zorg
git add zorg
echo "updated zorg to $num"
exit 0
```

and then:

```
$ git commit -m dink
updated zorg to 3
[master 76eeefc] dink
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

But note a minor flaw (won't apply to your case):

```
$ git commit
git commit
updated zorg to 4
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
[snip]
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git commit
updated zorg to 5
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
[snip - I quit editor without changing anything]
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
$ git commit
updated zorg to 6
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
```

Basically, because the pre-commit hook updates and `git add`s, the file keeps incrementing even though I'm not actually doing the commit, here.

[**Edit** Aug 2021: I need to emphasize that I *do not* recommend this approach.  Note that there are some oddball cases that can come up when using `git commit -a`, `git commit --include`, and `git commit --only`, including the implied `--only` that is inserted if you name files on the command line.  This is due to the fact that this kind of `git commit` creates a second, and sometimes even a third, internal Git index.  Any `git add` operations you do inside a hook can only affect *one* of these two or three index files.]

Comment: So basically it's a different kid of hack, right? Doing it my way the file is changed, but not committed until the next one

Comment: Yes.  I'm not sure I would be really happy with either approach; I'd rather have something like a Makefile to update things as needed, and something a bit more manual.  But it should work.

Comment: You could have you script do a `commit -a --amend` after your actual commit.

Comment: This doesn't seem super-safe to me. It's possible and not uncommon for there to be changes in the working-tree vs the index. If you usee git add you'll be adding whatever state is in the working tree to the index, which would be undesirable.

Comment: @tksfz: indeed, I don't *recommend* this at all. I just point out how it works.

Comment: @tksfz one could do `git commit zorg --amend`, so only the file with the counter is added.

Comment: @toolforger: you must be careful with `git commit --only` and `git commit --include` (`git commit zorg` means `git commit --only zorg` in this case, with neither flag given *explicitly*, but a file name given) as this changes the basic `git commit` action by creating two or even three separate index files. Any `git add` used during this special period, that lasts until the commit finishes or is aborted, affects only *one* of the multiple index files, with results that can be very confusing.

Comment: @torek do you have any background where I can read up the details? We're having plans for automatic local pre-actual-commit changes, and we wouldn't want surprises here.

Comment: @toolforger: I've written this up in detail in multiple SO answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65647202/1256452), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51587932/1256452), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56533336/1256452) for instance. This code inside `git commit` has evolved somewhat over the last decade, and the details are not documented and therefore subject to change, so don't depend too much on any one particular behavior.

Answer (score 19):

It turns out you can run "hooks" - they are actually handled by another mechanism - when *staging* files (at `git add` time) :

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion

(scroll down a bit to the "smudge" and "clean" diagrams)

Here is what I understood :

1. edit the `.gitattributes`, and create rules for the files which should trigger a dictionary update:

   `novel.txt filter=updateDict`
2. Then, tell Git what the `updateDict` filter does on *smudge* (git checkout) and *clean* (git add):

   `$ git config --global filter.updateDict.clean countWords.script`

   `$ git config --global filter.updateDict.smudge cat`