# Git - Can I commit my file but ignoring comments inside it?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have a simple C file:

```
int main(){
  // commented code
  return 0;
}
```

Can I commit this file with the commented line removed?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way for git to scan your files before they are committed, and preprocess the files with a script to remove the comments?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831536/can-you-change-a-file-content-during-git-commit

Comment: agree. some kind of precommit hook would be the way to accomplish this although this is a very unusual use of an scm tool.

Answer (score 0):

> GIT is a stupid content tracker

It doesn't ignore any changes to your files even a change in a char or comments to your file

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't. When you do git commit, It will eventually commit all of the content including your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can check clean filters [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html). You can define your own attribute to ignore the snippet/regex in code