# A work file is modified after it was added to staging. Then the file is committed to git without and add. What should happen?

Tags: git, staging

I noticed that after a modified file is added to staging in git and the file is changed again then followed by a commit without an add, there is no error nor warning. The latest changes in the working file get committed.  Is what initially added to staging thrown out?

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test/.git/

/tmp/test (master)
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"

/tmp/test (master)
$ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

/tmp/test (master)
$ echo A > my.txt

/tmp/test (master)
$ git add my.txt

/tmp/test (master)
$ git commit -m '1st' my.txt

[master (root-commit) c804a96] 1st
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 my.txt
```

at this point my.txt was committed with 'A'

```
/tmp/test (master)
$ echo B >> my.txt

/tmp/test (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   my.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")


/tmp/test (master)
$ git diff

The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
diff --git a/my.txt b/my.txt
index f70f10e..35d242b 100644
--- a/my.txt
+++ b/my.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 A
+B

/tmp/test (master)
$ git add my.txt
```

at this point work file has additional 'B' and was added to staging

```
/tmp/test (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   my.txt

/tmp/test (master)
$ git diff

/tmp/test (master)
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/my.txt b/my.txt
index f70f10e..35d242b 100644
--- a/my.txt
+++ b/my.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 A
+B

/tmp/test (master)
$ git diff HEAD
diff --git a/my.txt b/my.txt
index f70f10e..35d242b 100644
--- a/my.txt
+++ b/my.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 A
+B

/tmp/test (master)
$ echo C >> my.txt
```

at this point 'C' was added to the work file but not added to staging

```
/tmp/test (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   my.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   my.txt


/tmp/test (master)
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/my.txt b/my.txt
index f70f10e..35d242b 100644
--- a/my.txt
+++ b/my.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 A
+B

/tmp/test (master)
$ git diff
diff --git a/my.txt b/my.txt
index 35d242b..b1e6722 100644
--- a/my.txt
+++ b/my.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 A
 B
+C


/tmp/test (master)
$ git commit -m '2nd' my.txt
[master 4f574dc] 2nd
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
```

at this point commit was done without an 'add'

```
/tmp/test (master)
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

/tmp/test (master)
$ git diff

/tmp/test (master)
$ git diff --staged

/tmp/test (master)
$ git diff HEAD

/tmp/test (master)
$ cat my.txt
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 5):

From the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit :

> 3. by listing files as arguments to the `commit` command (without --interactive or --patch switch), in which case the **commit will ignore changes staged in the index, and instead record the current content of the listed files** (which must already be known to Git);

(Emphasize mine — *phd*)

Answer (score 3):

[phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66169993/1256452) is correct but deserves some expansion.

If you look at [the current documentation for `git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) (this evolves over time) it should include the `--include` and `--only` options:

> `-i`
> `--include`
>
> Before making a commit out of staged contents so far, stage the contents of paths given on the command line as well. This is usually not what you want unless you are concluding a conflicted merge.
>
> `-o`
> `--only`
>
> Make a commit by taking the updated working tree contents of the paths specified on the command line, disregarding any contents that have been staged for other paths. This is the default mode of operation of git commit if any paths are given on the command line, in which case this option can be omitted. [snip]

As that last-quoted sentence says, the *default* action, when adding path names to your `git commit` command, is to behave as `git commit --only`.  This particular action is achieved in a remarkably complex fashion, which can confound some pre-commit hooks.

The `--include` behavior is easier to describe, though this easy/simple description is slightly flawed (see below for a thorough and correct description).  Using `git commit --include` with:

```
$ git add file1.txt
$ git commit --include file2.txt
```

for instance is essentially equivalent to doing:

```
$ git add file1.txt
$ git add file2.txt
$ git commit
```

That is, the `--include` simply runs `git add` *for* you, though with the complication that if the commit *fails*, these files are magically "un-added".

The `--only` option, however, is much more complicated.  There's no simple way to describe it that is also fully correct.  To describe both of these properly, we need to understand Git's index in some detail.

#### Technical details: the index

When Git makes a new commit, it always<sup>1</sup> does so from an *index* or *staging area* or *cache*.  These are three words for the same thing.  The index / staging-area / cache is the *way* Git keeps track of what you would like committed.  Except for the special case of a conflicted merge,<sup>2</sup> the index holds your *proposed next commit*.  When you first `git checkout` or `git switch` to some commit, Git *fills in* its index *from* that commit.  So your proposed *next* commit matches your *current* commit.

You may have noticed here that I sometimes say *the index*, or *Git's index*, as if there is exactly one index, but I also sometimes say *an index*, as if there can be more than one.  The tricky part here is that **both are correct**: there is one particular distinguished index—*the* index—but you can have more than one.

Technically, the distinguished index is per-work-tree: if you use `git worktree add`, you not only add another working tree, but also another distinguished index, for that particular working tree.  You can find the file name of the distinguished index with:

```
git rev-parse --git-path index
```

which normally prints `.git/index`, but in an added work-tree, prints something else.  If `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` is set in the environment, it prints this variable's value.  This is how Git swaps to some alternate index file—or more precisely, it's the externally available mechanism that *you* can use, to point Git to some alternate index file, and a way for a pre-commit hook to *detect* a `git commit --only` invocation, for instance.

When you run `git add`, Git finds the existing entry, in the index, for the file you're `git add`-ing:

- If there is no existing entry—if this is a *new* file—Git copies the file into Git's index and now there is an existing entry: your proposed new commit has a newly added file, as compared to the current commit.
- Otherwise, there is some existing file in Git's index.  Git boots this file out of its index, and copies the work-tree version of the file into its index.  If this copy of the file is *different* from the copy in the current commit, `git status` will now say that the file is *staged for commit*.

So, `git add` simply updates your proposed *next* commit, which—at all times (but see footnote 2)—holds *a copy of every file that Git will snapshot*.  The copy that's in the *index* is the one `git commit` will use.

Now that we know how the index works, and that Git can use some extra, temporary index files that we can create, *now* we can really see how `git commit --include` and `git commit --only` work.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is correct for `git commit`, but if you use `git commit-tree` you can bypass the need for the index.  You must supply, to `git commit-tree`, the hash ID of the tree.  Where will you get that tree?  If you use `git write-tree`, that uses the index.  But you can get a tree from somewhere else, by, e.g., just using some existing tree, or using `git mktree`.  Note, however, that with `git mktree` you can build incorrect trees; the resulting commit will be impossible to check out.

<sup>2</sup>During a conflicted merge, Git expands the index.  This expanded index cannot be written out: `git write-tree` complains and aborts.  Using `git add` or `git rm`, you replace the expanded index entries with normal entries, or remove some entries entirely.  Once there are no expanded, non-zero-stage entries left, the conflicts are all resolved, because `git write-tree` can now write out the index: committing becomes possible again.

---

#### Technical details: `--include` and `--only`

To implement `git commit --include`, Git does this, more or less:

1. copies *the* index to a temporary one ("an" index);
2. runs `git add` on the *temporary* index, with the files you're include-ing;
3. attempts the commit.

An attempted commit can succeed—creating a new commit and updating the current branch name—or it can fail.  The commit fails, for instance, if `git commit` runs your editor and then you choose to delete the entire commit message.  Perhaps you were looking at something and realized you shouldn't commit yet, so you did that.  Or, the commit fails if the pre-commit hook decides that this commit is not ready yet.  Note that the pre-commit hook should look at the *temporary index* here!  It *should not* look at the *files in your working tree*.  That's not necessarily what will be in the commit.  Your proposed next commit is now whatever is in the *temporary index*.

If the commit fails, Git simply removes the temporary index.  The original index—*the* index—is untouched, so everything is now back the way it was.  The `git add`s in step 2 are magically undone.

If the commit *succeeds*, Git simply replaces *the* index with the *temporary* index.  Now the index and the current commit—which is the one we just made—match, so that nothing is "staged for commit".  That's how we like it.

Implementing `git commit --only` is harder.  There are still two cases: the commit can *fail*, or the commit can *succeed*.  For the "fail" case, we want to have the same thing happen as for `git commit --include`: *the* index, the main distinguished one, is undisturbed, as if we didn't even attempt to run `git commit`.  But, for the *success* case, `git commit --only` is tricky (and the documentation is, I think, slightly inadequate).

Suppose we do this:

```
$ git checkout somebranch         # extract a commit that has files
$ echo new file > newfile.txt     # create an all-new file
$ git add newfile.txt             # stage the all-new file (copy into index)
$ echo mod 1 >> file.txt          # append a line to an existing file
$ git add file.txt                # stage the updated file (copy into index)
$ echo mod 2 >> file.txt          # append *another* line to the file
$ git commit --only file.txt -m "test"
```

What would we like as the outcome, if this succeeds?  We told Git to commit the two-line addition.  Our working tree copy of the file is the two-added-lines version.  Should the *staged* file, proposed for next commit after our test commit, have just the *one* added line?  Or should it have *both* added lines?

Git's answer to this question is that it should have both added lines.  That is, if the `git commit` works, `git status` should now say nothing about `file.txt`; it should only say that `newfile.txt` is a new file.  The *two-added-lines* version of the file must therefore be the one in the proposed next commit, at this point.  (You might agree with Git, or disagree with it, but that's what the Git authors chose to have as the result.)

What this means is that we need *three* versions of the index at the point of `git commit --only` attempting to make the commit:<sup>3</sup>

- One—the original index—will have the new file in it, and the one added line.
- One—the index to be used by `git commit` to make the new commit—will *not* have the new file in it, but will have the two added lines to `file.txt`.
- The last one will have the new file in it, and the two added lines to `file.txt` in it.

The middle one of these three is the one `git commit` will use when attempting to make the new commit.  That has the two added lines, but not the new file: it's the `git commit --only` action, in action.

If the commit *fails*, `git commit` simply removes both of the temporary index files, leaving the original index—*the* index—undisturbed.  We now have one added line in the proposed next commit's version of `file.txt`, and we have the newly added *file* in the proposed next commit as well, as if we never ran `git commit --only file.txt` at all.

If the commit *succeeds*, `git commit` makes the *last* index—which has both the newly added file, and the two-added-lines version of `file.txt`—become *the* (main / distinguished) index.  The original index *and* the temporary index used for doing the commit both get removed.

This is what makes `git commit --only` so complicated.  Suppose you're writing a pre-commit hook yourself, and in this pre-commit hook, you plan to do two things:

1. Use a linter to make sure that there are no obvious bugs in any of the code that is to be committed (`pylint`, `pep8`, `go vet`, etc.).
2. Use a formatter to make sure that the code conforms to the project's standard (`black`, `go fmt`, etc.).

(In my opinion, step 2 is a mistake: don't do it.  But others like the idea.)

We now have three cases:

- You're doing a normal `git commit`.  `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` is not set.  There's just one index to worry about.  You read the files out of the (normal, everyday, standard) index, into a temporary directory, and lint them there.  If the linting fails, you stop and reject the commit.  If the linting succeeds, you format the files and `git add` them back to the (single) index, and let the commit happen.

  There's still a big problem here because the files that just got committed are the ones that were staged, not the ones in the user's working tree.  You can, perhaps, *check* the *working tree* files against the pre-updated, not-yet-formatted ones in the index, before `git add`ing any formatting updates.  If the working tree files match the index copies, it might be safe to reformat the working tree copies here too.
- You're doing a `git commit --include`.  There are two index files to worry about, but for linting purposes, you simply read the ones out of the index file that Git is using *now* for this commit, which is in `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` (which generally names `.git/index.lock` at this point).<sup>4</sup>

  You can treat this as before, because any formatting you do will go into the proposed commit, and it's just as safe to wreck the user's working tree files as last time.  You've already rejected the commit (and not done any formatting, presumably) if you're going to reject the commit; and if the commit succeeds, as you think it will, the user's `--include` files should be formatted too, after all.  On success, any updates you make to the temporary index will be in the real index, because the temporary index *becomes* the real index.
- You're doing a `git commit --only`.  There are now *three* index files to worry about.  One of them—the one `git commit` is going to use—is in `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`.  One of them—the one `git commit` plans to use to *replace* the main / distinguished index is in a file whose name you don't know.  The third one, the one that Git will drop back to on failure, is the standard main index.

  You can do your checking as usual: lint / vet the files that are in `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`.  That's the commit the user is proposing to make, after all.

  But now, if you format those files and add them to `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` ... well, the formatted files are the ones that will get committed.  That's all well and good.  But you also need to `git add` those formatted files to the temporary index file whose name you don't know!  And, when it comes to checking the working tree files against some index copies, you probably should use the copies that are in that temporary index file whose name you don't know.

If you *don't* **change** any files, but simply lint / vet them all and *check* for the desired formatting, these problems go away.  So it's best to just check stuff.  If the user wants the working tree files formatted according to the project's rules, provide them with a working-tree-files-formatter.  Let *them* run that, and then let *them* run `git add` on the updated files (or, if you really must, offer to add back the formatted files in the formatting script).

I've worked with a project where the pre-commit hook did check and then, if the formatting was wrong, checked `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` and would stop and do nothing for the tough cases, or offer to `git add` the reformatted files.  That too is an option, but it's a little bit risky since it's possible that Git will change some behavior, making the `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` test fail somehow.

---

<sup>3</sup>There are no doubt other ways to achieve the desired result, but given the fact that the index file is actually a *file* (at least initially), plus a bunch of existing Git code, this three-index-files trick was the one to use.

<sup>4</sup>This was the case the last time I tested all this, but that was quite a while ago—before the existence of `git worktree add`, which will clearly affect this, at least for added work-trees.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you torek for providing more than enough context to clear up the confusion.   There is more on it in [what"s the difference between git commit <file> and git commit --only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587518/whats-the-difference-between-git-commit-file-and-git-commit-only)

The moral of the story is --
*Do not specify files when committing unless you know what you are doing.*

Typical action:

```
 git commit -m "commit everything that is currently staged"
```

Atypical action:

```
git commit -m "commit only my.txt working file, ignore what is staged" my.txt
```

Specifying a file in the above commit implies an **--only** option

```
git commit --only -m "commit only my.txt working file, ignore what is staged" my.txt
```

This --only option says to commit only the file(s) specified in the commit command and ignore what is currently being staged.  After the commit, stages files will remain as they were, waiting to be committed.  I suppose there is use case for such a 'jumping the queue' behavior. But allowing implicit use of --only option is foolhardy. It is an accident waiting to happen.

Here is an analogy that can help remember this.
You and your friends arrive at a restaurant and are waiting (staged) to be seated together at a large table. The maitre d realizes the 2 people in your group of 12 are actually not part of your group and prioritizes specifically them (--only) to be seated first at table for 2. Instead of saying 'the next party to be seated follow me', the maitre d says 'you two follow me'.

As it has already been pointed out, the --include commit option is always explicit and says to also add a work file(s) specified on the command to whatever else currently already staged.

```
git commit -m "add almostforgot.txt to what is staged " --include almostforgot.txt
```

Is equivalent to:

```
git add almostforgot.txt
git commit -m "now have everything"
```