# Why do pre-commit hooks leave files "half staged"?

Tags: windows, git, pre-commit-hook

I'm trying to set up a pre-commit hook for formatting code, that would format  files and include changes in the commit. Several scripts that say they do this, but the ones I tried have the same problem: they leave files "half staged".

See for example [this script](http://www.duskborn.com/posts/git-pre-commit-clang-format-hook/). It properly adds files after modifying them, and says it should work on Windows. The fact that hooks don't work for me when they work for other people leads me to believe that something is up with my environment.

This happens when the hook modifies a file with a superfluous line break:

```
$ git status -s
A  src/hello.c
```

```
$ git commit src/hello.c

Add 'Hello World!'
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   new file:   src/hello.c
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   modified:   src/hello.c
#
```

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   src/hello.c

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   src/hello.c
```

```
$ git diff
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/hello.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
diff --git a/src/hello.c b/src/hello.c
index 5e4b595..768d31a 100644
--- a/src/hello.c
+++ b/src/hello.c
@@ -1,6 +1,5 @@
 #include <stdio.h>

-
 int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
```

```
$ git diff --staged
diff --git a/src/hello.c b/src/hello.c
index 768d31a..5e4b595 100644
--- a/src/hello.c
+++ b/src/hello.c
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 #include <stdio.h>

+
 int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
```

I would have expected the hook to leave a clean index. Instead it leaves the file staged without modification, but also leaving the file itself modified. Why does this behavior occur and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 4):

Warning: this answer is kind of long, but that's because it's really about all the pitfalls of this sort of pre-commit hook.  There are several, and it gets complicated in complex cases.

---

You didn't show the hook directly but you did have a link to [the link to the GitHub repository](https://github.com/sheredom/git-hooks) containing the hook; here's a [more direct link to the hook itself](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sheredom/git-hooks/master/hooks/pre-commit)).  I will quote a few lines from the hook.

The hook makes some rather brash assumptions, because when you run `git commit`, there are at least *three* of what I like to call "active copies" of each file, and this hook is not sophisticated enough to notice discrepancies between them.

#### Three copies of files, sometimes with different content

The three copies are:

- The committed copy in the current or `HEAD` commit.  This file literally cannot be changed—it's frozen for all time—but it is important because it's the basis we will use for comparisons.
- The *index* copy.  This file *can* be changed.  It's what you are proposing to commit: if your pre-commit and commit-message hooks permit the commit and all else goes right, the copy of the file that's in the index is the copy that will be committed.  Hence, you can think of the index—which Git also calls the *staging area*—as, essentially, the *proposed next commit*.

  These first two files—frozen `HEAD` copy, and index copy—are in a special, Git-only, compressed format.  While the index copy can be changed, that's always done by *replacing* it, typically using `git add` to overwrite it.  The `git add` command compresses a file into the Git-only format and places the compressed copy—well, technically, a reference to the compressed copy—into the index.
- The work-tree copy.  This file is an ordinary file that you can see and manipulate.

Now, you're using Git's LF/CRLF translation, as indicated by:

> ```
> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/hello.c
> ```

The actual translation happens when Git copies the file from the work-tree to the index—i.e., during `git add`—or when it copies the file from the index to the work-tree, e.g., during `git checkout`.  The extract-to-work-tree step changes LF-only line endings to CRLF line endings; the add-to-index step changes CRLF line endings to LF-only line endings.  (You can control this and change it around somewhat, but that's the usual scheme.)

#### `git status`, `git add`, and the existing hook

Let's go to the script now, and look at a few lines:

> ```
> for line in $(git status -s)
> ```

(technically this should be `git status --porcelain`, but at the moment they pretty much do the same thing: the main danger is that the `--short` output *could* be colorized, which would break the next bit)

> ```
>   if [[ $line == A* || $line == M* ]]
> ```

Now it's time to consider what `git status` prints.  [The documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) says, about the short format:

> ... the status of each path is shown as one of these forms
>
> ```
>    XY PATH
>    XY ORIG_PATH -> PATH
> ```
>
> where **ORIG_PATH** is where the renamed/copied contents came from.
>    **ORIG_PATH** is only shown when the entry is renamed or copied. The **XY** is
>    a two-letter status code. [snippage] **X**
>    shows the status of the index, and **Y** shows the status of the work tree.

(Aside: *copied* is not currently a possible status for `git status`.  The internal diff engine that `git status` invokes can set this, but to do so, the caller has to enable it, and `git status` just doesn't.  If `git status` got new command-line flags or configuration entries that enabled copy detection, you could get `C` status-es, but as of now you cannot.)

The key item here is that the first letter, which is what the script is testing here, is based on the *status of the index*.  That is, it's a summary of the result of comparing the `HEAD` commit to the index—to the proposed commit.  A file will be `A`dded if it's new in the index (does not appear in the `HEAD` commit), or `M`odified if it's in both the index *and* the `HEAD` commit, but the index copy is *different from* the `HEAD` commit.

The thing to realize here is that whether or not the *index* copy matches the *head* copy, the *work-tree* copy is a third file entirely.  It might be quite different from one or both of these other two copies!  **That's OK**, and in fact, that's deliberately the case if you use `git add -p` to selectively stage only *part* of the work-tree file.  Just keep it in mind as we plow on.

Now let's go back to the pre-commit hook script:

> ```
>     if [[ $line == *.c || $line == *.cc || $line == *.h || $line == *.cpp ]]
>     then
>       # format the file
>       clang-format -i -style=file $(pwd)/${line:3}
>
>        # and then add the file (so that any formatting changes get committed)
>       git add $(pwd)/${line:3}
>     fi
> ```

If the file name at the end of the line—which for `A` and `M` status files is just one file name; only `R` status files would have two names; but the script is faulty in not checking for `R` status files, since a file could be renamed *and* modified—ends in `.c`, `.cc`, etc., this runs `clang-format`.

The *input* to `clang-format` is the *work-tree* file.  The input almost certainly *should* be the index copy of the file, but it isn't.  So the script assumes that the index and work-tree copy match.

Having run `clang-format`, the script then runs `git add` to copy the (updated) work-tree file back into the index.  If we wanted to do this right, we'd need to format the index copy and then add the formatted index copy, which is pretty tricky.  That's probably *why* the script is a little lazy, but it's definitely worth noting.

The work-tree file written by `clang-format` is probably going to have LF-only line endings (see https://reviews.llvm.org/D19031).  This fits with the text of the warning:

> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/hello.c.

This is telling you that the current work-tree copy, `src/hello.c`, has LF-only line endings.  Git has been told that when Git copies from index back to work-tree, Git should change LF-only endings to CRLF endings.

#### More than three copies

Now things get complicated.  I mentioned above that there are *at least* three copies of each file, and then described the places these three copies live.  There's the `HEAD` commit, the index, and the work-tree.  The one flaw with this description is the phrase *the index*, as Git will sometimes use a *temporary* index.  That's the case for *some* `git commit` commands, but not for all of them.

The full story of `git commit` is that it always builds your new commit from *an* index, but not necessarily from *the* index.  There is a "the" index—one particular, distinguished index that goes with the work-tree.<sup>1</sup>  Then there are extra index files, that some Git commands create for various purposes—e.g., `git stash` creates a temporary index to save the work-tree, and `git filter-branch` creates lots of temporary index files as it runs.  Here, though, we're interested in `git commit`, and `git commit` will sometimes create one or two of its own temporary index files.

If you run `git commit`—with no extra arguments at all—`git commit` just uses *the* index file.  That's your proposed commit, and it already has all the files in it.  If your pre-commit hook runs `git add`, it copies new files into *the* index, displacing the old ones that were in the index, and eventually `git commit` writes out the new commit using the new files.  If the new files came from the work-tree, things mostly match up, except maybe for CRLF line endings.

But if you run `git commit --only` or `git commit --include`, or even just `git commit -a`, Git takes a twist.  If you run `git commit file1.cc`, that *means* `git commit --only file1.cc`, for instance, unless you add `--include` in which case it means `git commit --include file1.cc`.

To do these operations—actually including plain `git commit`—Git makes at least one temporary index file, although for plain `git commit` this happens as late as possible.  One temporary index file is named `index.lock` (well, `.git/index.lock`, depending on where your `.git` directory is).  This temporary index will be the true source of files for the new commit.  When the commit is finished, if it all succeeds, Git releases the lock by renaming `.git/index.lock` to be `.git/index`.

We can see these in action through a dummy `.git/hooks/pre-commit` that just prints the name of the environment variable `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`, then exits with a failure to prevent the commit:

```
$ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
$ git commit
$GIT_INDEX_FILE is .git/index
$ git commit -a
$GIT_INDEX_FILE is [path]/git/.git/index.lock
$ git commit --only cache.h
$GIT_INDEX_FILE is [path]/.git/next-index-53061.lock
$ git commit --include cache.h
$GIT_INDEX_FILE is [path]/.git/index.lock
```

So:

- A plain `git commit` uses the regular index file.  If your hook runs `git add` you'll replace files in the index.  When Git gets around to creating the lock file `index.lock`, it creates it *from* `index`, and when `git commit` finishes (assuming success), your changes to the index, made by your hook, will take effect.
- A `git commit -a` or `git commit --include` works similarly.  The lock is made earlier, but `git add` should update the `index.lock` in place, and when `git commit` finishes, your main index should have the updates.  (I have not tested this but it seems obvious.)
- But `git commit --only` makes a temporary index (`next-index-53061.lock`) as well as locking the main index and `git add`ing the `--only` files to the main locked index.  When the commit finishes, the new commit's files will be those from the temporary index, including anything you updated; but the *main* index will come from `index.lock`, which is the old index with the specific files updated.  *When* they got updated will control what is actually in that index.

---

<sup>1</sup>When you use `git worktree add` to create an additional work-tree, the extra work-tree gets its own singular index, so *the* index is the one that is paired with *the* work-tree: an added work-tree is a separate work-tree with a separate index.  The added work-tree also gets its own `HEAD`, which makes things especially complicated on Windows, but we don't need to go there.

---

#### Conclusion

These are the pitfalls to be aware of in commit hooks.  The implication of all of this is that, unless you want to get intimate with the innards of Git itself—of checking the name of `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`, for instance, and/or adding things to multiple index files—it's usually a bad idea to have hook *modify* the commit in progress.  Instead, it's usually wiser to *check* the commit-in-progress.  If the commit is good, let it proceed.  If not, remind the user to run whatever is required, and have the commit fail.

You *can* modify the commit-in-progress; you just have to be aware of these weird cases.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is using a `post-commit` hook like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for line in $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD)
do
    git add $(pwd)/${line}
done
```

An issue is that if the commit contains no changes, because the pre-commit hook removes them and commits anyway, the post-commit hook doesn't find the affected files and the index keeps the half staged look. This is probably something the pre-commit hook should make sure doesn't happen, though.