# Modify File/Git index in pre-merge-commit

Tags: git, git-merge, githooks

I want to change a respository file in a pre-merge commit before it is commied.

This should not necessarily have been changed by the merge.

The git hook will be more complex later, but the simplest example for my problem is the following.

I have created a file "pre-merge-commit" in the order .git/hook with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Name of the file modifyed by the hook
file_name="file_2.txt"

# content of the new line
new_line="new line pre merge hook"

echo "$new_line" >> "$file_name"

echo $GIT_INDEX_FILE

git add "$file_name"

git status

exit 0
```

Also I have a git respository with the two documents file_1.txt and file_2.txt

It contains 2 branches "main" and "branch_1".  After the separation of branch_1 from main, file_1.txt was changed in both branches in different places (no merge conflict).

When merging branch_1 into main i get the following output:

```
$git merge branch_1
.git/index
warning: in the working copy of 'file_1.txt', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   file_1.txt
        modified:   file_2.txt

Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.
 file_1.txt | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

With a subsequent git status command i get the following output:

```
$git status
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   file_2.txt
```

The question is now how can i modify a file with the pre-merge-commit an commit it with the following merge commit?

Now the changed file is only staged but somehow not commited.
I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524769/why-do-pre-commit-hooks-leave-files-half-staged/56533336#56533336) very detailed answer. Here it is explained that Git sometimes create  more than one index before commiting and that the current one is written to GIT_INDEX_FILE.
But as you see in the output of my hook it should use the default index ".git/index".
Where are the files staged that are commited with the merge-commit, how can I change that?

Did somebody know how to fix this problem?

**Edit: backround information**

The pre-merge hook is intended to be part of a larger program that will allow custom merge in git.
At the end this program should allow a user-defined selection of actions during a merge similar to FreeFileSync.
The user can choose for each file, which is changed in at least one of the two branches, a user defined action, what should happen with this file during the merge.
This is to prevent that files are automatically deleted or merged without informing the user and without the possibility to prevent or influence this.
In addition, it should be possible to merge not all files, but only a part.
Furthermore it should be easier to solve merge conflicts for less experienced git users.

The program first analyzes the differences between the two branches compared to the merge base before the merge, just as git does during a merge.
The git merge is then started. Occurring conflicts are registered by the program and solved temporarily with the ours method.
After completion of the merge process and before the commit, a GUI appears with all the actions and conflicts considered by git.
Afterwards, the user must resolve all conflicts guided by the program. In addition, he can change the actions considered by git.

After completion of the merge process and before the commit, a GUI appears with all the actions and conflicts considered by git. Afterwards, the user must resolve all conflicts guided by the program.
In addition, he can change the actions considered by git. E.g. keep a file, although it was deleted in the remote branch, do not merge certain files, although they were changed in the remote or check a successful automatic merge and possibly execute it differently.
This is mainly done from an overview similar to FreeFileSync.

After that the merge is finished in the user defined form.
There is my problem. In a merge without conflicts the user defined changes should be copied into the index in the pre-merge-hook.  I haven't found a way to solve this yet, except to end the merge normally and then do another commit with the custom changes.

In a merge with conflicts this is possible for all files during the phase while git asks the user to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: In general, trying to magically change what is to be committed is a terrible idea and all of the Git developers will tell you that (and I'm one of them).  What is the goal that you're trying to accomplish by doing this, so we can help you achieve it in a practical way?

Comment: I add more detailed informations to the question

Comment: What you describe is not a task that belongs into a Git hook, but a completely separate procedure. That procedure, after the user has worked through it, could be completed with a `git commit`. But it is certainly not *part* of `git commit`.

Comment: I know its not part of git commit. 

The completion with git commit only work in case of a merge conflikt but i search for the posibility to do the same in an merge without a merge-conflikt (see content of the main Question). 

My first try was to only stop the merge with the hook before commiting, the main programm should change meanwhile the index and the allowed the hook to continue with the commit. 
That don't work, so i try the more simple/basic method explained in the question to change the files in the git hook.