# Pre-commit-hook for Python project

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

How do I remove print statements in a Python project using pre-commit hook before checking in code to GitHub? Currently, I use black and flake8 pre-commit hooks. But they don't seem to have the option to check and remove print statements before checking in code.

Answer (score 3):

You could use flake8 plugin to check for print statements.

https://pypi.org/project/flake8-print/

Just add to your pre-commit config:

```
  - repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: <desired-rev>
    hooks:
      - id: flake8
        additional_dependencies: [flake8-print]
```

Comment: The "canonical" link (based on the repos metadata) should be to [github](https://github.com/pycqa/flake8), not gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [pre-commit framework](https://pre-commit.com/) only calls [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/index.html), you would need to check [its configuration](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html) to see if there is any setting which would trigger a print statement deletion (as opposed to [error/violation codes](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html))

Since that is not supported by flake8 itself, you would need to develop a [plugin to flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/plugin-development/index.html) in order to act on those error and delete the print lines.
If you do, don't forget to add the changes, as explained in "[Can you change a file content during `git commit`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16832764/6309)"

Answer (score 0):

`remove-print-statements` finally solved my problem

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 6.0.0
    hooks:
    - id: flake8
-   repo: https://github.com/dhruvmanila/remove-print-statements
    rev: v0.5.1  # Replace with latest tag on GitHub
    hooks:
    -   id: remove-print-statements
        args: ['--verbose']
```

---

I tried flake8-print doesn't work

```bash
$ flake8 --version
6.0.0 (flake8-print: 5.8.8, mccabe: 8.7.8, pycodestyle: 2.10.0, pyflakes: 3.0.1) CPython 3.11.3 on Darwin
```